# GenericForeignKey data migtation error: 'content_object' is an invalid keyword argument

Tags: python, django, django-migrations, generic-foreign-key

I want to create data migrations for a model(`Comment`) which has a `GenericForeignKey` relation. My model was made according to [django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#generic-relations) for [contenttypes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#module-django.contrib.contenttypes).

**Models:**

```
...
class NiceMeme(models.Model):
    """
        Example model.
    """

    name = models.CharField(max_length=140)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=get_path_to_store_nice_meme_images)


class Comment(models.Model):
    """
        Model to add comments to any other (non abstract) model.
    """
    ...
    user = models.ForeignKey(ExtendedUser)
    content = models.CharField(max_length=140)
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
    object_pk = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object = GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_pk')
```

**Data migration**:

```
...
def create_comment(apps, schema_editor):
    ...
    nice_meme = NiceMeme.objects.create(name='Nice nice meme')
    Comment.objects.create(
        user=user,
        content='Gott ist tot',
        poster_username='Friedrich',
        content_object=nice_meme
    )

...
operations = [
    migrations.RunPython(create_comment)
]
```

When I run `./manage.py migrate` I get:

`TypeError: 'content_object' is an invalid keyword argument for this function`

I have to say that I have used same code as `create_comment` inside a view and works well.

Im using django 1.7.7. Im not using south.

**Edit:**
I tried Shang Wang's answer.

```
Comment.objects.create(
    user=user,
    content='Gott ist tot', 
    poster_username='Friedrich',
    content_type=ContentType.objects.get_for_model(nice_meme),
    object_pk=nice_meme.id
)
```

Is not working either:

```
ValueError: Cannot assign "<ContentType: nice meme>": "Comment.content_type"  must be a "ContentType" instance.
```

Comment: I'm also having this same issue, and using Django 1.8.3 :/

Comment: Did you check the answer?

Comment: Im sorry. I was taking a vacation. I will look at it in a few hours. Thank you.

Answer (score 17):

As I said, I've been through this same problem and a colleague helped me with this tip:

You really need to set `content_type` and `object_pk` as +Shang Wang pointed out, but `ContentType` must be loaded using `apps.get_model` instead of directly import it.

So use this:

`ContentType = apps.get_model('contenttypes', 'ContentType')`

In your migration method and all should work :)

```
def create_comment(apps, schema_editor):
    ...
    ContentType = apps.get_model('contenttypes', 'ContentType')
    nice_meme = NiceMeme.objects.create(name='Nice nice meme')
    Comment.objects.create(
        user=user,
        content='Gott ist tot',
        poster_username='Friedrich',
        content_type=ContentType.objects.get_for_model(nice_meme),
        object_pk=nice_meme.id
    )
```

Comment: Is not working that way. `ContentType.objects` is actually `django.db.models.manager.Manager` so what I did was: `nice_meme_contenttype = ContentType.objects.get(
        app_label='comments',
        model='nicememe'
    )` model name must be lowercase. And now is working :)

Comment: Weird @LaraChícharo ... did you load ContentType using apps.get_model? I'm glad you've solved your problem BTW :)

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType

nice_meme = NiceMeme.objects.create(name='Nice nice meme')
Comment.objects.create(user=user,
                       content='Gott ist tot', 
                       poster_username='Friedrich',
                       content_type=ContentType.objects.get_for_model(nice_meme),
                       object_pk=nice_meme.id)
```

I think the problem is that your `content_object` field is just a simple way for your `Comment` model objects to access the foreignkey quickly, like:

```
obj = some_comment.content_object
```

It's not an actual field but a combination of 2 fields, so you cannot directly assign one single `NiceMeme` object to it.

Edit:

Sounds like you are using South, there's an issue described [here](http://south.aeracode.org/ticket/781). The solution is answered in another SO [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6211027/south-data-migration-instance-error-when-using-south-freeze-orm/6215957#6215957). Sounds like the solution is to freeze any model that your migration is related:

```
python manage.py schemamigration --auto yourapp --freeze contenttypes
```

You might need to freeze more apps:

```
python manage.py schemamigration --auto yourapp --freeze contenttypes --freeze someotherapp ...
```

I never encountered this problem before, so please read original post for more details, hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately, I got this: `ValueError: Cannot assign "<ContentType: nice meme>": "Comment.content_type" must be a "ContentType" instance.`

Comment: I updated my answer, I don't have enough knowledge to deal with this, but try the thread I found see if it helps.

Comment: Im not using south, Im using django 1.7.7. Sorry for telling you until now. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, the solution is to get ContentType object with the model name in lowercase:

```
content=ContentType.objects.get(app_label='appname', model='modelname')
```

For this question:

```
def create_comment(apps, schema_editor):
    ContentType = apps.get_model('contenttypes', 'ContentType')    
    nice_meme = NiceMeme.objects.create(name='Nice nice meme')

    Comment.objects.create(
        user=user,
        content=ContentType.objects.get(app_label='appname', model='nicememe')
        poster_username='Friedrich',
        content_object=nice_meme
    )
```